# Post mp3 bytes to API Gateway URL

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, http, aws-lambda

I have been trying to POST bytes to an API Gateway endpoint, using Python, integrated with an AWS Lambda function.

I receive a "Request too long" response message. It is a 3mb audio file. Could someone please point out what is the possible problem?

```
import requests
import json


bytes = open('audio.mp3','rb').read()

new_object = {
'audio' : bytes
}

response = requests.post(my_url,data=new_object)
print(response.text)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does the API endpoint need bytes as data or the file?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to post [binary data](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/binary-support-for-api-integrations-with-amazon-api-gateway/)
up to the [limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html).

I would suggest testing your endpoint with `curl` first. This will prove the binary configuration as outlined in the blog post. Then you can focus on getting `requests` to do the same.